# How can I make my <input type="submit" /> an image?

Tags: css, types, input, submit

I have a beautiful little CSS image that needs to be a button. I've tried about 20 different methods, none of  which work. I just either get a blank nothing or a border with nothing inside.

The html: http://lrroberts0122.github.com/DWS/lab6/level-2/

The image: http://lrroberts0122.github.com/DWS/lab6/level-2/images/button.png

The CSS: http://lrroberts0122.github.com/DWS/lab6/level-2/css/main.css

I can't change it to "submit" for certain reasons, so I need to figure out how to make this work with CSS. Thank you for your help!

Comment: IMO that looks more like a banner than a button. I would not expect that to send anything.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```css
input[type=submit] {
    background: url(http://lrroberts0122.github.com/DWS/lab6/level-2/images/button.png);
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    height: _the_image_height;
    width: _the_image_width;
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you. I wasn't including display: block, though I swear I had at some point and it didn't work. This is working great now, thank you. :D

Answer (score 49):

Use an image submit button, as [the doc](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_image.asp) says:

> `<input type="image">` defines an image as a submit button

```
<input type=image src=button.png alt="Submit feedback">
```

(I would not use an image suggesting snailmail when setting up an online form, but maybe there is some reason to create such associations.)

Comment: How come nobody has upvoted this answer yet? `<input type=image>` is exactly what OP wants, +1.

Comment: To be 100% this is entire code, You can set your own value as well

`<input type="image" src="sourceimage.jpg" name="yourname" value="customvalue">`

Comment: @ErykWróbel The `value` attr on `type="image"` elements isn't supported. [Mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image) states, "`<input type="image">` elements do not accept value attributes." and the [W3C docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#image-button-state-%28type=image%29) state, "The element's value attribute must be omitted.". Browsers appear to treat the `value` like image _alt_ text, but you should use the `alt` attr instead and this trumps the `value` attr anyway. The `value` attr on `type="image"` elements serves no purpose.

Comment: @duri it's because `input type=image` is misleading, Jukka should have precised the doc says: `The <input type="image"> defines an image as a submit button`

Comment: but this does not submit form onclick

Answer (score 2):

**simple and easy way to make an INPUT tag as an image**

```
<input type="submit" value="" style="background-image: url('images/img.png'); border:none; background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 100%;">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override the style given by the browser to the button.

For example adding this to your css does the trick for me (on Chrome):

```
.controls input {
   background: url(' http://lrroberts0122.github.com/DWS/lab6/level-2/images/button.png') -411px -540px no-repeat;
   width: 199px;
   height: 109px;
   border: none;
}
```

But really if you are not going to use the browser's css for the button, you should probably not use `<input type='submit'>` at all, and just insert the image (via an `<img src="" />` tag or a `<div>` with the image as background) and attach a click listener to it.

For example:

The html:

```
<div class="controls">
    <img src="/yourimage.png" />
</div>
```

The javascript (assuming you use jQuery):

```
$('.controls img').click(function(){... stuff to do...});
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML :**

```
<lable>From css class</lable><input class="input" onclick="alert('clicked')" type="button" value="" /><br/>
<lable>From HTML tag</lable>
<input type="button" style="background:url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/favicon.ico);" onclick="alert('clicked')"/>
```

**CSS :**

```
.btn{
    display: inline-block;
 background:url(http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/favicon.ico);
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.input{
    background: transparent;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    padding-right: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 5px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**JS Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/AJNnZ/26/

Answer (score -1):

Another way that's kind of hackish is this (using jQuery):

```
<div onclick="$(this).parent('form').submit();"></div>
```

Then you style your `div` any way you like.